# Understanding Azure Easy Tables on Mobile App on non-sql database

Tags: xamarin, azure-mobile-services

Based on this blog - https://blog.xamarin.com/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/ , the sample always used SQL as a database in conjuction with Easy Tables. We've tried to the Storage account instead of SQL database. Is this possible anyway?

Everytime we setup this, we always get "Easy Tables is not supported on your current App Service app. Please initialize your App Service app for Easy Tables support." It looks like it doesn't support Storage Account. Can someone verify this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We lodged a case to Azure Support and we finally get the answer. So basically the Easy Table is only working in SQL Database only NOT storage account.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the information I gave you in my answer? :-)

Answer (score 7):

First, be aware that Easy Tables are not supported with a .NET backend.
They only work when using the Node.JS backend (this means: the whole project has been created through the Azure portal and not via Visual Studio).

*Easy Tables* are by definition relational tables and are always backed by SQL Server. You can however *combine* them with another storage model by storing references inside an Easy Table (e.g. the name of an Azure Blob).

We have a blog post which goes into that direction: https://blog.xamarin.com/sync-files-between-devices-azure-file-sync/